# Center an inline block element with a link inside of a td

Tags: javascript, html, css

EDIT: Here is a JSBIN link: https://jsbin.com/zapuvupato/edit?html,css,js,output if it helps

I'm desperately trying to center an element. 
I've tried to text-align: center in a div outside of/inside of the td. 
It's set in the style class for the link and text.

It looks like the text-align is being applied, but it is not doing what I want, which is to center the entire inline-block, not just the link/text inside.

I am considering using HTML buttons if I can't get this to work.

```
td.TableButtonStyle {

    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(240,80,40);
    font-weight: bold;

}
.TableButtonStyle a
{
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}

.Bold
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

th.thCells{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size: 13pt;
    margin: 0px 5px;
}
td.TableCells {
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size: 13pt;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    margin: 10px 50px;
}
</style>

<table style = "margin: 10px 0px">
    <tr>
        <th class = "TableCells thCells Bold" style = "padding: 0px 15px">Deduction per Pay Period</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td id = "button1" class = "TableButtonStyle" style = "font-size: 14pt; padding: 15px 25px"></td>
    </tr>

</table>

<script>

    var buttonText1 = "<a href=\"javascript: giveButton('"+suggestedAnnualAmt1+"'); onclick:Incr1();\">$"+suggestedAmtPPP1+"</a>";

document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML = buttonText1;

</script>
```

Comment: Would you mind supplying some of your HTML?

Comment: Are you trying to center the td (or whats in td) considering th as the total width?

Comment: A td set to display as inline-block isn't going to fill the table width -- it's inline.  It'll be only as wide as necessary. So, it *is* centered. In your sample, the table is only as wide as the widest element (this particular td). If you increase the width of the td, the table width increases. https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/tcb7m7nn/ -- Perhaps you haven't shared enough sample markup??

Comment: seems to work here. did you put <style> inside <head> ?

Comment: @ntgCleaner, the HTML is the table in the center of the code. Are you saying I should include all of it?

Comment: @ravish.hacker I'm trying to center the inline-block element, inside of the td

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I didn't scroll down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably shouldn't make your `<td>` element a button.  What I would strongly suggest is to give your `<a>` the same style as your `<td>`, then remove the style from the TD and just tell the `<td>` to `text-align:center;`.

I've changed the `<td>` class to something else (`.center-inside`)

```
<td id = "button1" class="center-inside" style = "font-size: 14pt; padding: 15px 25px"></td>
```

And then changed the CSS to to style the button (and added some padding to make it large again)

```
td.center-inside {
  text-align:center
}
.TableButtonStyle {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(240,80,40);
    font-weight: bold;
    padding:20px;
}
```

Then I added the `.TableButtonStyle` class to your button in the javascript

```
 var buttonText1 = "<a class='TableButtonStyle' href=\"javascript: giveButton('"+suggestedAnnualAmt1+"'); onclick:Incr1();\">$"+suggestedAmtPPP1+"</a>";
```

https://jsbin.com/mezudaciqi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Out of curiosity why shouldn't I use a button in a td?

Comment: A TD is primarily used as a table cell to hold information.  The `<a>` inside of it should be used as a button.  It's just not "normal" and probably not compliant with W3 standards.  That's all.

Comment: Thanks much. Do you think for this page buttons would be more appropriate but in a different layout? I'm only comfortable working with HTML, Javascript, and CSS at this point, not yet jquery or bootstrap, but I plan on learning at some point and could possibly apply to this project.

Comment: As far as layout goes, It doesn't matter much how it gets laid out, as long as it works on all necessary browsers.  I've never been a fan of tables for non-tabular data, personally.  But if it works, then hey - no one should say otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

You td is not taking the whole width of the table. I may be wrong in understanding your problem. But if you want "a" to center within your "td". You should change your td to following (just adding width).

```
<td id="button1" class="TableButtonStyle" style="font-size: 14pt; padding: 15px 25px; width:100%">
```

Comment: when I do that it makes the inline-block take up the entire cell, which is not what I want. I tried setting the width to 50% but it's still left aligned.

Comment: In that case you will need another div. TD will have 100%, div is what your button is which can be sized properly (as required) and then your a inside div. For example see this:

http://codepen.io/ravish_hacker/pen/WwMWYW

Let me know if this is what you need, i will update my answer with the code :)

Comment: This gets me closer, but is there any way to do it without specifying the width? I would like the cell size to be dynamic based upon the length of the link text. Thank you for your help.